# htaccess Rewrite Rule duplicate - help me out please / RewriteRule ^(.*)\+apple\+fruit/$ ?q=$1 [L]

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this code in my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\+apple\+fruit/$ ?q=$1 [L]
```

this turns the searchquery in /keyword+apple+fruit/

thats ok.. the only problem is, if I type in /keyword+apple+fruit **+any+text+haha+** apple+fruit/
the htacces is showing content - but I don't want that.

is there any command to say - ok apple + fruit only **one time** in the url and the second time send a 404 or show nothing..

thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to exclude such a case:

```
RewriteCond $1 !apple\+fruit
RewriteRule ^(.*)\+apple\+fruit/$ ?q=$1 [L]
```